# Is there an English translation of Dante's "Divine Comedy" that mirrors the original's meter?

Tags: rhymes, meter

I know it would be extremely difficult to write anything in English using the Terza Rima and following the same rhyme pattern as feminine rhymes (the ones in which the penultimate syllable is stressed) are less abundant and prone to falling into cliche (measure-treasure-pleasure, human-woman, etc). And so translators opt for blank verse or even rhymed quatrains.

So: is there a translation that follows the original's meter and rhyme scheme?

Comment: ***Addendum: Terza Rima*** :  *English provides far fewer possibilities for rhyme than Italian, which stems much more directly from Latin, a language that contains regimented systems for noun and verb endings. As a result, writing terza rima stanzas, which depend so heavily on available rhymes, proves punishingly difficult in English. To circumvent this difficulty, most translators of The Divine Comedy sidestep the terza rima form, choosing to translate either in prose or unrhymed blank verse.* http://www.sparknotes.com/poetry/inferno/section14.rhtml

Comment: The following version appears to be in Terza Rima: *La Divina Commedia / The Divine Comedy -  A Translation into English in Iambic Pentameter, Terza Rima Form. By Paul Bruckman .*

Comment: Josh61: Yes, I'm aware of the difficulties, which I mentioned in my question. Thank you for the Bruckman reference. Unfortunately, in his version, masculine rhymes dominate, which is not quite the same thing.

Comment: @Ricky How about *Dante's Inferno, A New Translation in Terza Rima* by Robert Torrance?

Comment: @deadrat: definitely a good effort, and the flow is pretty good in spots, but he uses masculine rhymes throughout. So, yeah, until someone shows me something I haven't seen yet that ONLY uses feminine rhymes, I'll just live with the assumption that the task is, in fact, impossible. Just like it's probably impossible to translate any English verse epic of comparable length into Italian: a language in which masculine endings are so few and far between one gets the impression they might not even exist. Just look at any opera libretto.

Comment: Italian (including the Tuscan dialect of Dante's work) is a syllable-timed language, while English is stress-timed. Reproducing the meter of Dante's *Divine Comedy* in an English translation is not feasible.

Comment: @Ricky I take it that words in a "feminine rhyme" sound the same last syllable but stress the penultimate syllables.  Have I got that right?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on a different platform: Literature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John Ciardi's translation has been well received, and Laurence Binyon's was praised by Ezra Pound, IIRC.

Comment: Ciardi: only occasional rhymes,all masculine.

Comment: Binyon: masculine rhymes throughtout.

Comment: Could you include a citation from Dante and its English equivalent, please? Not only would that be illustrative, but I think, it would be quite interesting too.

Comment: If you understand Italian, you might be interested in Roberto Benigni's rendition of Dante's Divina Commedia, his soft Tuscan accent makes this passage quite mesmerising https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j57VMotWCx0

Answer (score 1):

How about Stephen Wentworth Arndt's translation in Iambic Pentameter and Terza Rima:

[Amazon book link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00JRD2MPW)

e.g.
  About the midpoint of our lifelong way[2]

I found myself in wooded darkness when

I lost the straight and narrow path to stray.

4   How hard to tell what it was like back then—

That savage wood, that rough and rugged lair;

The very thought brings back my fear again

Comment: Amazing, that. Even though the rhymes are all masculine rather than feminine. Still, the effort deserves praise in an of itself.